# Sleep timer for displaying text

Tags: java, android

In android, I am trying to display Ready Set Go one at a time with a slight delay before overwriting the next one.
This doesn't work for me.  I get the pause but no text is written.
Here is what I have tried so far any help is appreciated!

Once a user clicks the `Button` the on click calls readySetGo

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button_start_pause:
        readySetGo();               
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

public void readySetGo() {

    text_timer.setText("Ready");
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
            text_timer.setText("Set");
            SystemClock.sleep(2000);
            text_timer.setText("Go!!");

}
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is android.  What invokes this code?  Are you running this in a separate thread?  If so the thread may not have the ability to update the UI unless you set it up with the ability.

Comment: I made a couple edits above.  Basically a user clicks a start button then I want the text to say Ready.... Set.... Go....

Comment: There is almost never a good reason to use a Timer in Android.  The simple and correct way to do what you're trying to do is create a Handler and use its postDelayed method.

Comment: How do you use the Handler?  I'm pretty new at programming with android.

Comment: Google 'android handler'.  But basically you just create one in the UI thread, e.g., in your Activity's onCreate(...).  When you post Runnables to the Handler, they will run in the thread in which the Handler was created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use help provide by Kevin Krumwiede to get the following answer...

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button_start_pause:
        ready();
        set();
        go();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}

public void ready() {
    text_timer.setText("Ready");
}


public void set() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            text_timer.setText("   Set  ");

        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
}

public void go() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            text_timer.setText("  Go!!! ");

        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is in another thread, then the UI will not be updated until this method returns

see http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html